# Why is my view not updating on a view model change?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

**Parent View Model Command Method in `POSSalesViewModel`**
I know I might have broken the concept of mvvm with code below but I'm new to this and any improvement is appreciated.

```
private void AddProduct(ProductDTO productDTO)
{
    var ctx = (POSSalesDetailsViewModel)((POSSalesDetailsView)TabItems[_selectedTabIndex].Content).DataContext;
    ctx.ProductLines.Add(new ProductLine()
    {
        Product = productDTO.Description,
        Quantity = 1,
        ProductTradeChannelId = productDTO.ProductTradeChannelId,
        Amount = productDTO.Amount
    });
}
```

**Child View Model `POSSalesDetailsViewModel`**
Below collection is reached but the view is not being updated

```
public ObservableCollection<ProductLine> ProductLines
{
    get => _productLines;
    set { Set(ref _productLines, value); }
}
```

**Here the child view with the binding to the collection**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ProductTypesDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductLines, Mode=TwoWay}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Product, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                Header="Product" Width="Auto" />
        <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True"
                                                Binding="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                Header="Quantity" Width="Auto" />
        <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True"
                                                Binding="{Binding Amount, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                Header="Price" Width="Auto" />

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Delete"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Note**

The child view model instance is being created in the constructor to get a new instance each time (not the mvvmlight way)

```
public POSSalesDetailsView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new POSSalesDetailsViewModel();
}
```

Comment: Is there any System.Data.Error Binding in output of your Visual Studio?
And why didn't you make your `AddProduct` method in ViewModel, if, as i can see, you know the Commands.

Comment: @sTrenat there are no errors at all, the add product button is in another view, so how can i call the command from the parent viewmodel ? If that is what you mean

Comment: That's not a problem, problem is that you'r raising property Changed from another ViewModel, i seen that issue once and it wasn't trivial. If you could just place your AddProduct void in your viewModel, this could be much easier workaround.

Comment: Or just make simple EventAggregator/Messenger or something like this.

Comment: @sTrenat  i will try putting the method in the child view model, but as for the messenger, i'm not very familiar with that, that's the reason why i've chosen this approach.

Comment: @sTrenat ohh with my approach i will have to have two methods called AddProduct one in the MainViewModel which calls the AddProduct in the ChildViewModel, would that be of any benefit ?

Comment: If you have ViewModel, and childViewModel, you can just hold your childViewModel instance in parentViewModel, then from parent call child's method

Comment: Well, you can try :d

Comment: @sTrenat Strange, same result, i could verify through debugging that the products are added to the collection but still not displaying in the view.

Comment: Do you set DataContext somewhere else? i.e. in Xaml?
Make your `ProductLines` readonly, and check if there is error then

Comment: @sTrenat Just in the constructor

Comment: @sTrenat yup, this item can not be set read only, i have tried setting both the private field and the public one. both failed

Comment: Try this:

 private readonly ObservableCollection<ProductLine> _productLines = new ObservableCollection<ProductLine>();
        public ObservableCollection<ProductLine> ProductLines
        {
            get => _productLines;
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154180/discussion-between-strenat-and-mozart-alkhateeb).

Comment: Is the TabItem selected and currently visible?

Comment: @mm8 Actually I have resolved the problem using the messenger instance MVVMLight, but still curious to know why this did not work, yes the tab item is visible and selected.

Comment: Probably because you are adding items to the wrong instance of the view model.

Comment: @mm8 Actually the instance is correct but modifying the collection from outside the view model seems not to invoke the Setter of the collection, and even after I forced the PropertyChanged to be invoked through debugging. the view is not affected.

Comment: The setter is not supposed to be invoked when you are adding an item to the collection. But you should see the newly added item anyway.

Comment: @mm8 aha, thanks for the information, yea it shouldn't. I should have guessed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging my issue i figured out where the issue was.

```
        <TabControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <!-- this is the header template-->
            <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding Header}" />                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <!-- this is the body of the TabItem template-->
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:POSSalesDetailsView/>//**Problem is here**
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

The problem was that a user control instance was created on parent view load. so when i requested adding new user control inside a tab item a new instance was created. and the data was not appearing. so i moved the user control to this section.

```
                <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding Header}" />
                    <local:POSSalesDetailsView Grid.Row="1"/> // **Here**
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: @sTrenat I wanted you to know how my issue was resolved, since even after using the messenger with a token the issue was not resolved until I fixed this.